# VS 15 Prev 3: "Unable to download deployment content from" Azure storage account using container blob

Tags: azure-blob-storage

"Unable to download deployment content from 'https://xxxxxxxxx.blob.core.windows.net/template/templates.json'. The tracking Id is 'xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxxx'. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-deploy for usage details."

Comment: Please provide more information about what went wrong with your deployment. What do you do in VS 15 Prev 3? How we could reproduce this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to pass SAS token along with your blob URL. For example if your container is private then you are not able to download the files from that container so, select your file/template then there is option like **Generate SAS**.

Once you have generate SAS token for your file/template then you will have the access for that file/template.

**Example:**

> https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.blob.core.windows.net/mastertemplates/StorageAccount.json?sp=r&st=2018-11-06T09:03:01Z&se=2018-11-06T17:03:01Z&spr=https&sv=2017-11-09&sig=9%2FWHwrXT4%2FK7QH75oVVNw5gUQChIJV9hEZy%2Fro4ZdZ0%3D&sr=b